# How to make difference between FileInfo and DirectoryInfo in a file explorer in list view

Tags: c#, listview, windows-forms-designer, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I would like to make a file explorer with Windows Forms, i already have done a few things, but when i would like to use the DoubleClick event of my ListView I dont know how to code that file explorer needs to act differently when I make the doubleclick on a file or a folder.

My goal is:

1. Clicking on a file - Loads its text into a TextBox
2. Clicking on a directory - Opens it and loads it into the listview.

I know how to do 1. and 2. as well, I just don't know how can I make my DoubleClick function know what the selected item in ListView was 1. or 2.

I build my ListView like this:

```
private void miOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InputDialog dlg = new InputDialog();
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        DirectoryInfo parentDI = new DirectoryInfo(dlg.Path);
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo df in parentDI.GetDirectories())
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] { 
                df.Name, df.Parent.ToString(), 
                df.CreationTime.ToShortDateString(), df.FullName });
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }

            foreach (FileInfo fi in parentDI.GetFiles())        
            {                                                   
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] { 
                fi.Name, fi.Length.ToString(), 
                fi.CreationTime.ToShortDateString(), fi.FullName } );
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you putting files and directories into your ListView? Whatever is doing that has to store whether what it put was a file or a directory. Your DoubleClick has to use the stored thing as well.

Comment: `switch (listViewItem) { case DirectotyInfo di: DoDirectoryThings(di); break; case FileInfo fi: DoFileThings(fi); break; }`

Comment: I edited my original post, sorry i forgot to write that down.

Comment: you have an empty catch statement...you might be hiding a problem potentially...empty catch statements are always bad...you might want to modify the message you give the user...but as the programmer...you always want to know what happened in order to take proper action

Comment: You are not assigning the `ListViewItem` any `DirectotyInfo` or `FileInfo`. If you assigned it to the `Tag` property, you could later test whether the `Tag` is the one or the other, e.g. with the switch statement from my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `DirectoryInfo` or the `FileInfo` objects to the `Tag` property of the `ListViewItem`. I.e

```
...
var lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] { 
    df.Name,
    df.Parent.ToString(), 
    df.CreationTime.ToShortDateString(),
    df.FullName
});
lvi.Tag = df;
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
...
```

or for the file info:

```
lvi.Tag = fi;
```

Then, after having selected an item in the listview:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Show the first item selected as an example.
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
        switch (listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag) {
            case DirectoryInfo di:
                MessageBox.Show($"Directory = {di.Name}");
                break;
            case FileInfo fi:
                MessageBox.Show($"File = {fi.Name}");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
FileAttributes fileAttributes = File.GetAttributes("C:\\file.txt");

if (fileAttributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
    Console.WriteLine("This path is for directory");
else
    Console.WriteLine("This path is for file");
```